# Segmentation fault in Ruby C API executable when loading ruby file that contains #coding: binary

Tags: c, ruby, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to call simple ruby function using Ruby C API, When executing the compiled output I get segmentation fault only when `#coding: binary` is in the ruby file, if i remove this line the code runs fine,  I hope you can help me, Thanks.

**C Code (./func.c)**

```
#include <ruby.h>
int main(){
 VALUE obj;
 VALUE result;
 VALUE map;
 ruby_init();
 rb_require("./func.rb");
 obj=rb_str_new_cstr("");
 map = rb_hash_new();
 rb_hash_aset(map, rb_str_new2("key"),rb_str_new2("val"));

 result = rb_funcall(obj, rb_intern("func"), 1, map);
 return 0;
}
```

**Ruby Code (./func.rb)**

```
#coding: binary
def func(opts)
    puts opts['key']
end
```

**Compile flags**

```
gcc func.c -o func -I/home/wh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-linux -I/home/wh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0 -L/home/wh/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ -lruby-static -lm -pthread -lcrypt -ldl -rdynamic
```